# Can I use WordPress as a login provider in my application?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I already have a website running WordPress and I have an additional service, which however isn't built on WordPress. The problem is, that the service will be used only by registered users on the WordPress website.

What I would like to do, is use WordPress authentication, as if users were logging in via OpenID, Google, Facebook connect or anything in that manner. Is that even possible to do with WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you can. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/ is a SSO (Single Sign On) provider.

Or try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-userlogin/ (work with versions up to 3.0.5)

Comment: thanks for a suggestions, but that plugin isn't compatible with WordPress 3.x :\ at least that's what the website says

Comment: What version of wordpress are you running.  3.0.5?

Comment: 3.2.1, the latest version. I'm updating with every new release.

Comment: Well at least try it.  Create a backup before doing so